# How do I pull a specifc commit in SmartGit and overwrite the local file so that I can open the previous commit in PyCharm?

Tags: python, git, bitbucket, pycharm, smartgit

As the title says, I need to pull a specific commit using SmartGit and overwrite the local file so that I can open the previous specific commit in PyCharm. Google didn't help me out much.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you looking for `git reset`?

Comment: @mstrap I'm not sure. I just need to pull a specific commit, because the last two commits were defective. I don't know how to go back in time and work with a previous commit.

Comment: So you want to get rid of your last two local commits? Then `git reset --hard` is probably what you are looking for. In SmartGit, use **Local > Reset**. Note that in the Log, you can always toggle **Lost Heads** if something goes wrong and you can reset back to your original commits.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking out the desired commit as a new (local) branch - see http://www.syntevo.com/smartgit/documentation/6.5/show?page=commands-branch#checkout

Specifically, under "Checking Out Commits" it says

> On the Log window, select the commit to switch to and then 
>   select Check Out from its context menu.

At the command line this is the equivalent of

```
$ git checkout -b newbranch <SHA of desired commit>
```